# Error in as.data.frame.default: cannot coerce class to a data.frame - submit button to .csv

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

i have a small shiny dashboard where i have two buttons - submit and reset

i'm trying to take the user input from a checkboxGroupInput and append it to a loaded .csv

i'm getting the error when i run the app:

Error in as.data.frame.default: cannot coerce class to a data.frame

i'm obviously a bit lost here in my server section of the code. my reset button works just fine, and i have some kind of understanding of how the syntax works there. i'm also at a bit of a disadvantage because i am not using google sheets as a part of the solution and the example i'm trying to follow uses google sheets so the part of the code regarding updating the sheet throws me off.

here's the code so far:

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

# Libraries to load

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(googlesheets4)
library(markdown)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(pander)

# Load local test data

dbrp_data <- read.csv(file = '/home/osrs/dbrp_data.csv')
dbrp_data1 <- read.csv(file = '/home/osrs/dbrp_test_data1.csv')


# Dashboard page

ui <- dashboardPage(
    
    
    
    # Begin dashboard header
    dashboardHeader(title = "DBRP"),
    
    # Begin dashboard sidebar
    dashboardSidebar(
        
        # Begin sidebar menu
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Artifact Entry", tabName = "artifactentry")
            # End sidebar menu
        )
        # End Dashboard sidebar
    ),
    
    # Begin dashboard body
    dashboardBody(
        
        # Begin tab items by tab name
        tabItems(
            
            # Begin first tab item
            tabItem(tabName = "artifactentry", h2("Artifact Entry"),
                    
                    # Begin first fluid row - artifact entry for submit and reset buttons
                    fluidRow(
                        
                        # Begin first box of first fluid row - artifact entry
                        box(h3("Submit or Reset Data"), width = 7,
                            
                            # Begin first column of first box of first fluid row - artifact entry
                            column(3, h4("Submit Data"),
                                   # Submit action button
                                   actionButton("submit_artifact_entry", label = "Submit")
                                   
                                   # End first column of first box of first fluid row - artifact entry
                            ),
                            
                            # Begin second column of first box of first fluid row - artifact entry
                            column(3, h4("Reset Entries"),
                                   # Reset action button
                                   actionButton("reset_artifact_entry", label = "Reset")
                                   
                                   # End second column of first box of first fluid row - artifact entry
                            )
                            
                            
                            # End first box of first tab item - artifact entry
                        )
                        
                        # End first fluid row - artifact entry for submit and reset buttons
                    ),
                    
                    # Begin second fluid row - widgets to test area
                    fluidRow(
                        
                        # Begin box of second fluidRow - widgets to test area
                        box(h3("Widgets to Test"),
                            
                            # Begin first column of second fluidRow - widgets to test
                            column(4, h4("Widgets"),
                                   
                                   # Checkbox widget to test
                                   checkboxGroupInput("dbir", selected = NULL,
                                                      h4("Select Rating"),
                                                      c(
                                                          "Low" = "Low",
                                                          "Medium" = "Medium",
                                                          "High" = "High",
                                                          "Critical" = "Critical"
                                                      )
                                                      # End checkbox widget to test
                                   )
                                   
                                   
                                   # End box of second fluidRow - widgets to test area
                            )
                            
                            # End box second fluidRow - widgets to test
                        )
                                                
                        # End second fluidRow - widgets to test area
                    )
                    
                    
                    # End first tab item
            )
            

            # End tab items by tab name
        )
        

        # End dashboard body
    )
    

    # End dashboard page
)

# Begin server functions
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    # Rest button for artifact entry page
    observeEvent(input$reset_artifact_entry, {
        
        # Reset data breach rating check box
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "dbir", choices = c(
            "Low" = "Low",
            "Medium" = "Medium",
            "High" = "High",
            "Critical" = "Critical"), selected = NULL)
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$submit_artifact_entry, {
        
        submit <- reactive(c(
            input$dbir
            )
        )
        
        # append write of data on submit
        write.table(submit, "dbrp_test_data1.csv",
                    append = TRUE
                    
        )
 
    })

    # End server functions
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

cheers~!

update:

i changed the code in server to this:

```
    observeEvent(input$submit_artifact_entry, {
        
        submit <- data.frame(c(
            input$dbir
            )
        )
        
        # append write of data on submit
        write.table(submit, "dbrp_test_data1.csv",
                    append = TRUE
                    
        )
```

it no longer crashes the app when i click submit, but i get this error every time i click submit:

Warning in write.table(submit, "dbrp_test_data1.csv", append = TRUE) :
appending column names to file
Warning in write.table(submit, "dbrp_test_data1.csv", append = TRUE) :
appending column names to file

also nothing is written to the file when i go back and check it

Comment: Check what is in your `submit` variable (eg. `str(submit)` or `print(submit)`). I'm guessing it's not something that write.table can use, and it's trying to convert it to a data.frame, unsuccessfully.

Comment: As `submit` is reactive, try `write.table(submit(),...`